# Aurelia - How do I register a singleton in a route's child container?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I'd like to scope a singleton to a route so that a new instance is created every time the user re-enters the route. I thought I could register an instance on the (automatically created) child container in the route view-model, but I get the error:

> ERROR [app-router] ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SomeOtherClass' before initialization

How do I register a singleton within a route's container so that it is scoped only to that route?

My route VM looks like

```ts
import {autoinject, Container} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {SomeOtherClass} from '...some-other-class'; // The actual relative path

@autoinject
export class SomeRoute {

  constructor(private container: Container) {
    container.registerInstance(SomeOtherClass);
  }
}
```

The class I want to register is autoinjected into various components within the route. That class looks like

```ts
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject
export class SomeOtherClass {

  constructor(private dep1: Dep1, private dep2: Dep2) {
    // Stuff that I want to re-run every time the user (re)enters the route
  }
}
```

and other classes just inject it like so

```ts
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {SomeOtherClass} from '...some-other-class'; // The actual relative path

@autoinject
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor(someOtherClass: SomeOtherClass) {
    // Use the singleton instance within this route
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah, I found the problem! The error message was a little misleading to me.

The problem was that `Foo` was importing a view-model class (because I stuck a public static constant on it). That view-model class hadn't been initialized by the router yet. I moved the constant to another class (didn't really belong there anyway) and the error went away.

I also confirmed that `Foo`'s singleton was now scoped to the route's child container.